# How to deploy Ownable contract with Hardhat and Ethers?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, ethers.js, hardhat

When I deploy an `Ownable` contract via hardhat (hardhat-deploy in particular) to Optimistic Kovan, it doesn't seem to set the owner correctly, whereas when I deploy the same set of contracts via Remix, it does set the owner correctly. I have a github link to the repro here: https://github.com/zawazawa01/ownable-repro.

What's the correct way to deploy these contracts?

My script is the following:

```
module.exports = async ({getNamedAccounts, getUnnamedAccounts, deployments}) => {
    const {deploy} = deployments;
    const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts();
    const accounts = await getUnnamedAccounts();
    await deploy('TestOwnable', {
      from: accounts[0],
      args: [],
      log: true,
    });
  };
  module.exports.tags = ['TestOwnable'];
```

and the relevant network config is

```
    'kovan-ovm': {
      url: 'https://kovan.optimism.io',
      ovm: true,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY],
    },
```

The contract is barebones:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC
pragma solidity 0.7.6;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

// Inherited
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract TestOwnable is Ownable {
    constructor() Ownable() {}
}
```

I deploy this with command `yarn deploy:ovm`, which runs `hardhat deploy --network kovan-ovm`, and the transaction succeeds, but according to the logs we can see that ownership is not transferred to the deploying account: https://kovan-optimistic.etherscan.io/tx/0x9740d01219838ea7a7c8155dc30df9fb12a69105014386a14df4aedd9e401aa9#eventlog.

On the other hand, deploying with remix, the transfer of ownership does succeed: https://kovan-optimistic.etherscan.io/tx/0x2b92f8ae26994055d19b5f90fe975dc605177da38865e247cd24f980659315d0#eventlog.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Consider starting from my [Hardhat template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template), which comes with a simple deployment script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your contract as follows

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract TestOwnable is Ownable {
    constructor() Ownable(msg.sender) {}
}
```

The alternative is to add the owner as an argument in the constructor.

```
contract TestOwnable is Ownable {
    constructor(address initialOwner) Ownable(initialOwner) {}
}
```

Deployment should look something like this:

```
await deploy('TestOwnable', {
  from: accounts[0],
  args: [owner.address],
  log: true,
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at Hardhat's [Deploying your contracts](https://hardhat.org/guides/deploying.html), they have an example.

It should be something along these lines -

```
  const TestOwnable = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("TestOwnable");
  const testOwnable = await TestOwnable.deploy();
  await testOwnable.deployed();
```